# Create a ViewBag so it can be iterated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of dropdownlist as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ValResponse[i].Building, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Building
```

The thing is that for each iternation of i for model.ValResponse[i].Building , I need a viewbag that is specific to that iteration. Is there a way to do a viewbag iteration for with the same new - in this case VieweBag.Building?

Comment: Not sure I'm clear on what you're asking. But for starters why does this need to be a ViewBag? But to the question, you can put anything in ViewBag so why not put an array of Collections, looking something like this `ViewBag.DropDowns[i].Building`? Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @MickelsonMichael Yes correct, looking for something like ViewBag.DropDowns[i].Building.

Comment: So then what's stopping you from doing that? As long as you store the entries in the expected order, you shouldn't have any problems. [ViewBag is dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) so there are very few restrictions on what you can put in. A collection of collections is perfectly viable. I'd still recommend using a view model instead, but then again I've never been a fan of ViewBag